# Changing Row into Columns

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle10g, pivot, dynamic-sql

I am currently getting this output from my query:-

```
Count(Total)| Type1
-----------------
 24            T1

  22           T2
```

But I want the output like this:-

```
 T1   T2
----------
 24   22
```

Note that `Type1` column can contain any values like T1,T2,T3 so I cannot fix the values in the query. I am using Oracle 10g,  how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle 10g does not have a `PIVOT` function so you can use an aggregate with a `CASE`:

```
select 
  sum(case when type1 = 'T1' then total end) T1,
  sum(case when type1 = 'T2' then total end) T2
from <yourquery goes here>
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f9b9/5)

Or you can implement this directly into a query similar to this, using the `SUM()` aggregate will count each occurrence that matches the `type1` value in the `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  sum(case when type1 = 'T1' then 1 else 0 end) T1,
  sum(case when type1 = 'T2' then 1 else 0 end) T2
from yourtable
```

If you have an unknown number of values to transform into columns, then you will want to use a procedure similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct type1 from yourtable order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
              ' , sum(case when type1 = '''||x.type1||''' then 1 else 0 end) as '||x.type1;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from yourtable';

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then to execute it:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x
```

Comment: Type1 Column can contain any values like T1,T2,T3...I can not fix it in query

Comment: @Devesh please see my edit, I added a sample of a dynamic version

Comment: @Devesh if there is another question about this, then you should post a new question.  When posting a new question, explain any of the errors that you are getting.

Comment: I need one query help.I have posted in this forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410464/oracle-10g-query-format