# Pivot on Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, pivot

I am using oracle 10g.
I have a temp table TEMP.

TEMP has following structure:-

```
USER COUNT TYPE
---- ----- ----
   1    10   T1
   2    21   T2
   3    45   T1
   1     7   T1
   2     1   T3
```

I need a query which will show all types has column names,and types can have any value like `T1, T2,..Tn` and result will be like:-

```
USER T1 T2 T3
---- -- -- --
   1 17  0  0
   2  0 21  1
   3 45  0  0
```

and User column will show all the users and `T1, T2` column will show total count of types.

Comment: You'll need to give a more clear example of what your result should be with the sample table.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson please check sample output in edited question

Comment: there is not static sql solution unless your T1.. Tn amount is finite and known. otherwise, dynamic sql and ref cursors are your options

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Oracle 10g, there was no `PIVOT` function but you can replicate it using an aggregate with a `CASE`:

```
select usr,
  sum(case when tp ='T1' then cnt else 0 end) T1,
  sum(case when tp ='T2' then cnt else 0 end) T2,
  sum(case when tp ='T3' then cnt else 0 end) T3
from temp
group by usr;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a42bb/1)

If you have Oracle 11g+ then you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from temp
pivot
(
  sum(cnt)
  for tp in ('T1', 'T2', 'T3')
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68e3f/4)

If you have an unknown number of values to transform, then you can create a procedure to generate a dynamic version of this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(1000) := 'select usr ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct tp from temp order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
              ' , sum(case when tp = '''||x.tp||''' then cnt else 0 end) as '||x.tp;

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from temp group by usr';

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

then to execute the code:

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot(:x)
print x
```

The result for all versions is the same:

```
| USR | T1 | T2 | T3 |
----------------------
|   1 | 17 |  0 |  0 |
|   2 |  0 | 21 |  1 |
|   3 | 45 |  0 |  0 |
```

Edit: Based on your comment if you want a `Total` field, the easiest way is to place the query inside of another `SELECT` similar to this:

```
select usr,
  T1 + T2 + T3 as Total,
  T1,
  T2,
  T3
from
(
  select usr,
    sum(case when tp ='T1' then cnt else 0 end) T1,
    sum(case when tp ='T2' then cnt else 0 end) T2,
    sum(case when tp ='T3' then cnt else 0 end) T3
  from temp
  group by usr
) src;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a42bb/5)

Comment: ,I need a column between USER and T1 to show total count of Types,how can it be done through query.Output should be like:-      | USR |Total | T1 | T2 | T3|                                       ----------------------      Total column  will show sum of T1,T2,T3

Comment: @little your best bet is it place your query inside of another select, similar to this demo - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a42bb/5

Comment: ,I need one more help.I have to show total of all rows with header.Total will be added with header where total is sum of that column.Like User|Total_Total|T1_Total|T2_Total|

Comment: Then you will use column aliases on the select statement. So select usr as User, etc. but if you have another question you should post a new question.

Comment: ,i have posted it as a new question,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037006/show-sum-of-columns-with-column-name-in-oracle10g

Comment: bluefeet,It is my new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14037006/show-sum-of-columns-with-column-name-in-oracle10g#comment19392139_14037006

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code for table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_TEMP
(
    USR   NUMBER
   ,CNT   NUMBER
   ,TP    VARCHAR2 (10)
);

INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP VALUES (1,10,'T1');
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP  VALUES (2,21,'T2');
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP  VALUES (3,45,'T1');
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP  VALUES (1,7,'T1');
INSERT INTO TBL_TEMP  VALUES (2,1,'T3');
```

And, here is a code for your request:

```
  SELECT T1.USR
        ,SUM (T1) T1
        ,SUM (T2) T2
        ,SUM (T3) T3
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT USR FROM TBL_TEMP) T1
        ,(SELECT T2.USR
                ,DECODE (T2.TP, 'T1', T2.CNT, 0) T1
                ,DECODE (T2.TP, 'T2', T2.CNT, 0) T2
                ,DECODE (T2.TP, 'T3', T2.CNT, 0) T3
            FROM TBL_TEMP T2) T2
   WHERE T1.USR = T2.USR
GROUP BY T1.USR;
```

And, the result is what you wanted.

Check it at SQL Fiddle Link [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1c8b9/1/0)

Comment: +1. For future users, [Oracle 11g introduces pivot functionality](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the query:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
CURSOR V_CUR IS
 SELECT DISTINCT "TYPE" FROM temp_tbl;

V_QUERY CLOB;
V_COLUMNHEADING CLOB;
V_ROW V_CUR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN V_CUR;
  LOOP
  FETCH V_CUR INTO V_ROW;
  EXIT WHEN V_CUR%NOTFOUND;
    V_COLUMNHEADING:=CONCAT(V_COLUMNHEADING,''''||V_ROW."TYPE"||''' AS "'||V_ROW."TYPE"||'",');
  END LOOP;

  IF NVL(V_COLUMNHEADING,' ') <> ' ' THEN
        V_COLUMNHEADING := SUBSTR(V_COLUMNHEADING,0,LENGTH(V_COLUMNHEADING)-1);
  END IF;

  V_QUERY := CONCAT(V_QUERY,'select * from (select * from temp_tbl)a pivot (sum("COUNT")for "TYPE" in ('||V_COLUMNHEADING||'))b;');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_QUERY);
END ;
```

To select data, use statement `OPEN CUR_TURN_TIME FOR V_QUERY;` in place of `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_QUERY);`, where `CUR_TURN_TIME` is the cursor declared in the package.