# How to convert row to column in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the my table,

```
Seqno Datetime        Exe Time
2000  1/8/2016 17:00  1253
1999  1/8/2016 13:00  1000
1998  1/8/2016 11:00  999
1997  1/7/2016 17:00  1456
1996  1/7/2016 13:00  2000
1995  1/7/2016 11:00  555
```

Am expecting the output as below format? am using oracle 10g. If possbile to retrive with out using Listagg function.

```
Date     5pm  1pm  11am
1/8/2016 1253 1000 999
1/7/2016 1456 2000 555
```

Comment: You could look into the pivot operator in oracle.

Comment: What if 1/7/2016 14:35 suddenly shows up in your table?

Comment: @chirs : Oracle 10g has pivot concepts?

Comment: Oh, I don't know. 10g is officially unsupported now, isn't it?

Comment: Oracle 10g does not support PIVOTs. I would suggest using a case statement as this will work to produce output in the manner you want.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410464/pivot-on-oracle-10g