# Pivot Table for oracle 10g and less

Tags: excel, oracle, pivot

I have 3 Field names viz. port, date, and corresponding value for each pair of (port,date) etries
I want to create a PIVOT table in oracle 10g and lesser versions, where the rows will be the Port and the columns will be the Months but NOT the Date as similar to the original database and the entries would be the sum of values.
The following table can be easily generated 
[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqP1O.png)

and then through excel a pivot table can be made where Port will be in the rows and Month will be in columns.
But I want to create the pivot table directly in oracle.

Please help me.
I use oracle 10g and lesser version

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410464/pivot-on-oracle-10g

Comment: Here, my requirement is different. I have the values for each (Port, Date) pairs, from where I can generate (Port,Month) pairwise values through oracle. And now I want to create a Pivot table from the later generated table, which I am unable to do. Because of the presence of data-field, I am unable to use similar query

Comment: You cold make 12 columns for the months if you constrain the data to be of the interval of one year.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am unable to use the codes properly